# finding longest similar subsequence in a string

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Suppose I want to find the longest subsequence such that first half of subsequence is same as second half of it.

For example: In a string abkcjadfbck , result is abcabc as abc is repeated in first and second half of it. In a stirng aaa, result is aa.

Comment: I don’t get it. Where is `abc` anywhere in the first string? And why is the result of the second string not `aaa`? Clearly that’s longer.

Comment: I guess subsequence does not mean that the indices must be consecutive. The resulting aa is either [index 0, index 1], [index 1, index 2], or [index 0, index 2].

Comment: aaa has "aa" result because in "aa" first half is same as second half.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task may be treated as a combination of two well known problems.

1. If you know in advance some point between two halves of the subsequence, you just need to find the best match for two strings. This is [Pairwise alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment#Pairwise_alignment) problem. Various dynamic programming methods solve it in O(N<sup>2</sup>) time.
2. To find a point where the string should be split optimally, you can use [Golden section search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_section_search) or Fibonacci search. These algorithms have O(log N) time complexity.

Comment: So, what I understand from ur method is that .. from i = 1: n, create two strings and just perform longest common subsequence over them. So, it will be order of n * (n * n) to find the longest subsequence   with similar halves. But, can we generate all such strings possible(not just the longest)? for example, for aaa, we will have 3 such strings possible aa,aa,aa. (first "a" with second "a", first "a" with third "a", second "a" with third "a")

Comment: Searching the longest subsequence with these algorithms is O(N^2 log N) because with Golden section search you don't need to split the string on every possible position. But this does not allow to get all subsequences. Generating all subsequences is a completely different task and it should be addressed by some other methods.

Answer (score 0):

In a first pass over inputString, we can count how often each character occurs, and remove those with occurrence one.

```
input: inputString
data strucutres:
Set<Triple<char[], Integer, Integer>> potentialSecondWords;
Map<Char, List<Integer>> lettersList;

for the characters c with increasing index h in inputString do
  if (!lettersList.get(c).isEmpty()) {
    for ((secondWord, currentIndex, maxIndex) in potentialSecondWords) {
       if (there exists a j in lettersList.get(c) between currentIndex and maxIndex) {
         update (secondWord, currentIndex, maxIndex) by adding c to secondWord and replacing currentIndex with j;
       }
    }
    if potentialSecondWords contains a triple whose char[] is equal to c, remove it;  
    put new Triple with value (c,lettersList.get(c).get(0), h-1) into potentialSecondWords;
  }
  lettersList.get(c).add(h);
}
find the largest secondWord in potentialSecondWords and output secondWord twice;
```

So this algorithm passes once over the array, creating for each index, where it makes sense, a Triple representing the potential second word starting at the current index, and updates all potential second words.

With a suitable list implementation and n being the size of inputString, this algorithm has worst case runtime O(n²), e.g. for a^n.

Comment: Can you please explain the algo?